# changing order of files

Tags: linux, shell-script, batch-rename

I have a series of files named in alphabetical order (xaa.tif to xdg.tif). I need to reverse the order of the filenames so that the last file is processed first in a script. I would like to rename them by adding a number at the beginning of the filename (01xdg.tif to 60xaa.tif).

How can I do that with a bash script on Linux?

Answer (score 1):

*Because* the file names contain no special characters, including spaces, this can be pretty easily accomplished using `ls -r` (that's `-r` for `--reverse`, not `-R` for `--recursive`).

```
/tmp/todo$ ls
/tmp/todo$ touch ab bc bd ef
/tmp/todo$ ls
ab  bc  bd  ef
/tmp/todo$ ls -r
ef  bd  bc  ab
/tmp/todo$
```

Then you can rename the files using something like:

```
num=1
for file in $(ls -r)
do
    mv $file "$(seq --format='%02g' $num $num)${file}"
    num=$(( $num + 1 ))
done
```

This uses `seq` to format the number to use two digits (`2`) zero-padded from the left (`%0`) with no decimal places (`g`) for a total format string of `%02g`. There's probably a more efficient way to do it, but with so few files, I wouldn't bother micro-optimizing.

This simply iterates over the list of files (in reverse order), renames each one in turn and increments a counter for each rename.

The final result is:

```
/tmp/todo$ ls
01ef  02bd  03bc  04ab
/tmp/todo$
```

Note that the above may very well fall apart if the file names have anything more unusual in them than simple a-z, periods and digits to begin with. Particularly, I'm not sure how well it'll handle spaces.

Comment: `seq --format='%02g' $num $num` ?? How about `printf "%02d%s" $num "$file"`

Comment: Also `(( num++ ))` is a little tidier

Comment: @glennjackman I couldn't recall the exact syntax when I wrote the answer, and honestly didn't feel like spending too much time on that which was better spent on making the overall answer as clear as it could reasonably be. Really, this is about renaming 60 files, so performance should be a non-issue. And I even point out that there are probably more efficient ways to accomplish the same goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can user sort command in Linux

lets say the directory contains following files

```
# ll /tmp/sort_folder
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Dec 18 19:51 a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Dec 18 19:51 b
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Dec 18 19:51 v
```

The sort command will give you output as below(by default ascending)

```
# ll /tmp/sort_folder | sort
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Dec 18 19:51 a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Dec 18 19:51 b
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Dec 18 19:51 v
```

To reverse sort(descending) you can we -r(reverse) option for sort command

```
# ll /tmp/sort_folder | sort -r
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Dec 18 19:51 v
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Dec 18 19:51 b
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Dec 18 19:51 a
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this fails horribly if any of the file metadata is different. `sort` will sort the input lines in lexigraphical order, and has no special understanding of the `ls` output format.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
Count=0
ls -r | while read FileName
do
    FmtCount=`printf %02d $Count`
    mv -i $FileName $FmtCount$FileName
    Count=$((Count+1))
done
```

Here's the explanation:

- `ls -r` lists the files in reverse order
- `printf` formats the count into two zero-padded digits
- The backquotes turn the output into a string

I think the rest is self-explanatory, but if not please ask